# Create Ionic TypeScript wrapper from my Cordova Custom plugins

Tags: typescript, cordova, ionic-framework, ionic3

I have created a Custom plugin for Cordova and is working fine. But now I want to use the same plugin in Ionic 3.
I am able to use the same custom plugin in Ionic using the below command in typescript file:

> declare var **PluginName**: any;

But in this case when I run the **ionic serve** command it fails to read and prompts the message, PluginName not found.
So I want to wrap my plugin in Ionic Native typescript where I can use the below command to implement my plugin into the App:

> import {**PluginName**} from '@ionic-native/**PluginName**'

I found this link : 
https://medium.com/@sangkhim/build-your-first-cordova-plugin-for-ionic-native-38d29a170145

But I was unable to understand properly.

Can anyone suggest me how can I achieve this with my plugin?

Answer (score 1):

Clone the official [ionic-native repo](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native) and [follow the instructions](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/blob/master/DEVELOPER.md) to build your wrapper within the ionic-native project.  You can then copy the built plugin into your project's node_modules/@ionic-native directory and use it as you've described.

Comment: Hi jared, Am I going to clone the Ionic-Native Repo and then put my Custom Plugin Inside the @ionic-native folder and the add it to my repo?